# "Pharaoh" or "the Pharaoh"?

Tags: grammar

Should we use "the Pharaoh" or simply "Pharaoh"? Since it is a title I think it should be preceded with "the". But I see it used both ways. Why?

Comment: There were [many pharaohs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pharaohs). "The Pharaoh" probably refers to the one during the time of Noah or Moses.

Answer (score 1):

One question would be whether you are addressing a Pharaoh, in which case you would not use a prefacing article, or speaking about him, in which case you would.

When speaking about POTUS you would say "the President held a press conference" but if addressing him you would say "Mr. President". Speaking about a coach, you say "the coach" but speaking to him you say "Coach".

It may also be that accepted usage would allow dropping the "the" when speaking about a pharaoh if it is clear that a specific pharaoh is understood. So you would say "Pharaoh" meaning Pharaoh Raamses without having to use both the title and name at each mention.

Comment: Regarding your last point, will "Moses said to Pharaoh"  be fine even if the particular Pharaoh has not been specified any where in your text? Or only if he has been specified earlier?

Answer (score 0):

I think that "Pharaoh" is more correct.   While it is true that "Pharaoh" refers to the title, it was also used like a name.  In the original Hebrew,   the word is "Pharaoh"  and not "the Pharaoh"

Comment: Not all languages use the definite article identically.